# PHP Apache - Handle 1000 simultaneous request

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

**Question moved from Stackoverflow**

I have a PHP script which handles request from client. 
I should be in a situation to handle 1000 concurrent requests (using apache benchmark). When I presently run apache benchmark with 300 concurrent requests, I am able to handle all the requests.But when I exceed the 300 mark, apache is not able to handle it.
(It exits with apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104) )

And this is the apache error log.

```
[Thu Oct 29 11:20:34.984542 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6244] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 29 11:20:34.984581 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6244] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 29 11:21:38.638943 2015] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 6244] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

This is the mpm prefork config -

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers              8
    MinSpareServers           5
    MaxSpareServers          20
    MaxRequestWorkers        256
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   4
</IfModule>
```

From the above config, I could handle 256 * 4 > 1000 requests concurrently. I am presently using a 8 core machine with 16GB of RAM.

Is it possible for my apache server to handle 1000 concurrent requests?

**More Details on what my PHP code Does**

On receiving the client request, my php script in turn starts a python script. This python script, telnets into 50 different machines in parallel using the python multiprocessing. On an average , it takes 0.5 seconds to complete one request.

**EDIT**

As per the suggestion of shodanshok.I changed the mpm worker conf file to this:-

```
   <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        ServerLimit              300
        StartServers              50
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers        300
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0 
   </IfModule>
```

But the benchmarking still does not complete, it exits very early . And this is what i found on the apache logs.

```
[Thu Oct 29 12:14:42.372184 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29261] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 29 12:14:42.913499 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1397] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 29 12:14:42.913539 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1397] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what `MaxRequestWorkers` and `MaxConnectionsPerChild` do. From the [manual page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers):

> The MaxRequestWorkers directive sets the limit on the number of
>   simultaneous requests that will be served. Any connection attempts
>   over the MaxRequestWorkers limit will normally be queued, up to a
>   number based on the ListenBacklog directive. Once a child process is
>   freed at the end of a different request, the connection will then be
>   serviced.
>
> For non-threaded servers (i.e., prefork), MaxRequestWorkers translates
>   into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to
>   serve requests. The default value is 256; to increase it, you must
>   also raise ServerLimit.
>
> For threaded and hybrid servers (e.g. event or worker)
>   MaxRequestWorkers restricts the total number of threads that will be
>   available to serve clients. For hybrid MPMs the default value is 16
>   (ServerLimit) multiplied by the value of 25 (ThreadsPerChild).
>   Therefore, to increase MaxRequestWorkers to a value that requires more
>   than 16 processes, you must also raise ServerLimit.

and

> The MaxConnectionsPerChild directive sets the limit on the number of
>   connections that an individual child server process will handle. After
>   MaxConnectionsPerChild connections, the child process will die. If
>   MaxConnectionsPerChild is 0, then the process will never expire.

In short, in prefork mode, `MaxRequestWorkers` is the **total** number of concurrent connection allowed. `MaxConnectionsPerChild` is here only to tell the child to die after so many connections.

In other words: raise your `MaxRequestWorkers` setting will solve your problem.

Comment: hey @shodanshok . I have edited the answer. I am sorry . It is mpm prefork and mpm worker. As with PHP it is recommended to us prefork. Prefork has a limitation of maximum number of request workers to be 256. Apache does not allow me to increase beyond that.

Comment: it makes sense on the MaxConnectionsPerChild. I have set it back to 0.

Comment: To increase MaxRequestWorkers over 256, you had to increase ServerLimit also. Its written in the manual ;)

Comment: Hey shodanshok, thank you! But i changed the config, but it exits very early. Please check the updated question.

Comment: As stated in the doc: "Any attempts to change this directive during a restart will be ignored, but MaxRequestWorkers can be modified during a restart". So **stop** you apache instance, then **start** it. And please, really read the manual ;)